# How to convert a digit in a string number to int

Tags: c++

hello i have a problem i am trying to convert a string like "12314234" to int
so i will get the first number in the string.
from the example of string that is shown above i want to get '1' in int.
i tried :
`string line = "12314234";
 int command = line.at(0);`
but it puts inside command the ascii value of 1 and not the number 1.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a numerical character ('`0`' – '`9`') to its corresponding value, just substract the ASCII code of '`0`' from the result.

```
int command = line.at(0) - '0';
```

Comment: The C/C++ standard do not guarantee ASCII. They do guarantee that all numerical character codes are adjacent and in asending order so that '5' - '0' will result in 5 though.

Comment: Nor is it really C++.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
int command = line.at(0) - '0';
```

The numerical values of digit characters are required to be next to each other. So this works everywhere and always. No matter what character-set your compiler uses.

Answer (score 2):

The standard function to convert an ascii to a integral value is strtol (string to long) from stdlib (`#include <cstdlib>`). For information, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strtol and then the link off that page entitled Using strtol correctly and portably.  With strtol you can convert one numeric character, or a sequence of numeric characters, and they can be multiple bases (dec, hex, etc).

Comment: Yeah, except thats C, not C++.

Comment: @mathepic #include <cstdlib> and then use std::strtol().

Comment: Yeah, but you have to convert the `string` to a `char *`

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to convert a string like "12314234" to int

Boost has a library for this:

```
int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to join this party late but what is wrong with:

```
int value;
std::string number = "12345";
std::istringstream iss(number);
iss >> value;
```

If you are passing hexadecimal around (and who isn't these days) then you can do:

```
int value;
std::string number = "0xff";
std::istringstream iss(number);
iss >> std::hex >> value;
```

It's C++ and has none of this hackish subtraction of ASCii stuff.

The `boost::lexical_cast<>()` way is nice and clean if you are using boost. If you can't guarantee the string being passed will be a number then you should catch the thrown error.